# How to make an image a link towards it's own source using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble finding a way to make all the images on my website *links to themselves* so the image clicked on opens in a new window.

Currently I'm using HTML to do this, however, I'd rather only have the image code in my HTML and add the links with jQuery.

For example, the HTML loads like this:

```
<img src="/img/01.jpg">
```

I would like to change it to this, with jQuery:

```
<a href="/img/01.jpg"><img src="/img/01.jpg"></a>
```

I have been approaching this as follows:

```
$("img").wrap($('<a>',{
  href: ''
}));
```

I simply don't know how best to continue. How to pull the link from the `img` and place it after the 'href' bit.

Comment: What "trouble" specifically are you having?  What code have you written and what doesn't work as expected?  Are you able to select your `<img>` elements?  Are you able to read their attributes?  Are you able to create your `<a>` elements?  Are you able to add an element to the DOM?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks David, I see how I'm not articulating my question in an informative way. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you require by providing a function to `wrap()` which return the `a` element to wrap that specific `img` instance in. As this function is applied to each `img` individually you can use `this.src` to retrieve the `href` property to set on the `a` element you're creating. Try this:

```js
$("img").wrap(function() {
  return $('<a>', {
    href: this.src
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="/img/01.jpg" />
<img src="/img/02.jpg" />
<img src="/img/03.jpg" />
```

Comment: Questions. Why use `var` and not `const`  ? Why assign this to another variable ? when the scope of `this` won't change ( in the return )  so you could use it directly there  ( for eg : `$("img").wrap(function() {
  return $('<a>', {
    href: this.src
  });
});`? . If you use `this` why not use it to get the src. `$("img").wrap(function() {
  const src = this.src;
  return $('<a>', {
    href: img.src
  });
});` ?  Also you would need to add target blank as attribute :) . This is not a negative comment. I am just curious and want to learn from the more experienced users.

Comment: I used `var` here out of habit, as I've been working on some legacy systems. If you're happy for this to not work in IE10 or lower, feel free to use `const` instead. `this` from `wrap()` needs to be re-assigned as it will have a different scope in the `$('<a>')` object. `target="_blank"` is a good point, and can easily be amended by the OP if needed. Never be afraid to ask questions :)

Comment: as i see here -> https://jsfiddle.net/mtau0kfr/ it doesn't change scope . If it did, it should've been referring to the 'a' object, right ? And who in the hell uses IE 10 ? :)) On a more serious note. I am used to use `const` and `let` because i'm also using Babel. But your point is correct about the use of `var` in this case

Comment: You're right. I tested this when I was writing the snippet and got an error, although admittedly I didn't pay much attention to it. I'll amend the answer. Thanks. Also, lots of enterprise level systems still rely on IE10. It makes me a sad panda

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the explanation and your time. Cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` to iterate your `a` elements. Then you get the value of `href` with `attr('href')`.

`find` will allow you to get the `img` element associated with your link.

Then you just have to set the value got by `attr('href')` to your `img` with `attr('src', myValue)`.

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', href);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/img/01.jpg"> <img src=""> </a>
<a href="/img/02.jpg"> <img src=""> </a>
```

Comment: unfortunately I now realise I have been asking the question very inarticulately. Correct me if I'm wrong; is your code doing the exact opposite of what I need? I might be able to now add an <a> to my img and give the <a href> the information from the <img src>.

Comment: @Jordy I didn't see your edited answer. Yes, that does not respond to your issue :) Well, you have your answer now

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort though. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you have a bunch of `img` with `src` attribute. And you want when the user clicks on them to open a new tab with the `src` link.

You can do that by wrapping them inside an `a` tag, or you could make a click function that opens a new tab with that link.

Solution 1. Wrap with `a` tag.

```js
const img = $("img");
$(img).wrap(function() {
   return `<a target="_blank" href=${$(this).attr('src')}></a>`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250"/>
```

Solution 2. With click function

```js
const img = $('img');
$(img).click(function() {
  const src = $(this).attr('src');
  window.open(src, '_blank')
});
```

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

for each image with the same CSS class name surround it with an anchor of the image's src

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var someimage = document.getElementsByClassName("myimg"); 
for(var i = 0; i<= someimage.length -1; i++){
 var mysrc = someimage[i].src;
 $(someimage[i]).wrap("<a href=\""+mysrc+"\" target=\"new\"></a>"); 
 }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="myimg" src="http://imgsv.imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/sample1_l.jpg" alt="" style="width:50px;height:50px">

<img class="myimg" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/69/69407.png" alt="" style="width:50px;height:50px">
```